# Page does not contain a definition for a method when I try to fill a textbox with the data from an external file in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I have been trying to link a TextBox to an external text file in a Visual Studio 2012 Windows 8 store app and eventually be able to edit the contents of this TextBox afterwards with a SAVE button, but unfortunately i get the error which is shown in the link of the screenshot. I am running Windows 8 on a virtual machine !

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlegq.png "ERROR
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnOQO.png "Place of the error in the designer page

COde that i am using for filling the TextBox:

```
 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadWords(@"Assets\AdminPageKS1words.txt");

    }

    async private void LoadWords(string filename)
    {
        var wordList = new List<String>();
        // this method reads line separated words from a text file and populates a List object // 
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        // begin the file read operation 
        try
        {
            // open and read in the word list into an object called words 

            StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            var words = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(sampleFile);
            // add each word returned to a list of words declared 
            // globally as List wordList = new List();

            foreach (var word in words) 
            { 
                wordList.Add(word); 
            }
            List1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, wordList);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // handle any errors with reading the file
        }
```

Code that i am using for the SAVE button:

```
        async private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

         // locate the local storage folder on the device
     Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

      // create a new text file in the local folder called “File.txt”
    StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("File.txt",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

       // write text to the file just created – text comes from a textblock called wordlistBox
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, List1.Text); 

      // display a message saying that file is saved.
   messageLabel.Text = keystage + "File saved";

    }

    public string keystage { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where is your List1_textChanged event in AdminPage.xaml.cs file?

Comment: There isn't one there

Comment: that's the reason you are getting the error. If you don't want it remove it (textChanged = List1_TextChanged) from your XAML file

Comment: yes, without it the code has no mistakes, but it does not work again, the words from the text file still don't appear in the textbox

Comment: are there any errors while executing the code? are you getting values in your wordList list?

Comment: no that is what i was saying, no errors at all and i am not getting any values at all

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me, but you have a Try..Catch block which is effectively ignoring any exceptions. I'd suggest one of the following:
- Add a breakpoint to the start of Page_Loaded to check that it's actually being called, then step through the code to see whether there's an exception. 
- Modify your Catch Block to write out the error information:

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messageLabel.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: The problem is now solved ! I just added this "LoadWords(@"Assets\AdminPageKS1words.txt");" to the original page event
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e).
Thak you !